# How do I keep jQuery UI Accordion's one div Active by default?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $.fn.togglepanels = function(){
      return this.each(function(){
        $(this).addClass("ui-accordion ui-accordion-icons ui-widget ui-helper-reset")
      .find("h3")
        .addClass("ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom")
        .hover(function() { $(this).toggleClass("ui-state-hover");})
        .prepend('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>')
        .click(function() {
          $(this)
            .toggleClass("ui-accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-state-default ui-corner-bottom")
            .find("> .ui-icon").toggleClass("ui-icon-triangle-1-e ui-icon-triangle-1-s").end()
            .next().slideToggle();
          return false;
        })
        .next()
          .addClass("ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom")
          .hide();
      });
    };

    $("#notaccordion").togglepanels();
    });
```

I have tried a multi accordian example but my aim is to keep the divs open on page load. 
How to do that here.

Answer (score 0):

@TempData["DefaultPane"] is the name of the pane you want open by default.

```
$("#accordion").accordion({ active: @TempData["DefaultPane"] });
```

Comment: thanks Mirhasd for the answer but I could not get you because i need all the divs opened up on page load. I have tried modifying ur code to         $("#notaccordion").togglepanels({ active: "accordionDiv" }); where accordionDiv is my div id. But still did not work. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using the jQuery accordion function first and see what it does before you create your own togglepanel function. After the accordion is created and is working, you can customize the accordion behavior with your togglePanel function.  Try this first: $("#notaccordion").accordion({ active: "accordionDiv" });